# How to make subquestions in Google Forms?

Tags: google-forms

I want to make form with different length dependent on some previous responses.

For example:

- Q1: Do you like cats? Yes/No
- Q2 (Q1=Yes): Which kind of cat do you like most?
- Q2 (Q1=No): Why do you dislike cats?

Or make some questions visible only in some conditions (Yes to some previous question).

How can this be done (if it is possible) in Google Forms?

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/91666/88163

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can, by using the *Go to page based on answer* feature. This implies that you have to divide your form into *pages*, which is easy to do.

Given you have already created your form with three questions:

1. Do you like cats?
2. Which kind of cat do you like most?
3. Why do you dislike cats?

Create a page for each section of your form:

1. Click the *Add item* button
2. Select *Page break*
3. Move question 2 into your new page (drag-and-drop)
4. Add a new page break
5. Move question 3 into your new page

You should now have three pages; one for each question.

Now make your first question a *Multiple choice* question, and tick the *Go to page based on answer* checkbox:

[image: Multiple choice question with Go to page]

Add options to your question (*Yes* and *No*). For each option, select the page to go to if that option is selected:

[image: Question options]

On page 2 (with the question *Which kind of cat do you like most*) you would want to skip the next page (*Why do you dislike cats*):

[image]

That's it. I've setup an example form here, feel free to play with it:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1wGKiAO8s1CjgW5puNrCZYooa7mFJHq0BygBvw3fHFNg/viewform