# Google forms hierarchical multiple choice questions

Tags: google-forms

Supposing I have 2 multiple-choice questions concerning:

1. Country students are from: ..... (choices include USA, UK, China ....)
2. States where they are from: **then if they selected USA in the first question, the options shown will be LA, Cali or somewhere in the US but not somewhere in UK  or Russia**

Can we do this in Google forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The easiest path is to create a section for each choice which will hold the specific questions for each country.

Then make your initial question around which country.

You then make that question `go to section based on answer` by clicking on the three dots in the corner.

You'll then have additional options for each answer and can set it up accordingly.

The screenshot below asks which country and based on the answer jumps to a section where there is a country specific option for cities.

[image]

Comment: Does it mean we have to create as many page breaks and sections as the number of countries in the world? Is there any less painful way?

Comment: That's the only way I'm aware of with Google Forms. There might be some way to script it, if you're familiar with javascript.

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me with the script?