# Google Forms: Subquestion based on lookup

Tags: google-forms

This question is similar to the one here:
[How to make subquestions in Google Forms?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40833/how-to-make-subquestions-in-google-forms)

I want folks to pick from a list of projects, and then on the second question, pick from a list of phases for the project they chose.  So (e.g.) I've selected project 20050.  Now show the list of phases for (just) project 20050.

For the project list I'm using FormRanger and it works great.

I know you can use the "Go to page based on answer" feature, but there are 2100 distinct projects, each with up to 200 phases.  This would mean 2100 separate pages which seems crazy.  Plus if I were to use FormRanger I'm assuming I'd have to go into 2100 separate pages to update the individual choices.

Is there any way to look up the list of choices on a question dynamically based on the prior answer?  Or do you have to have every (roughly 22,000) combination pre-determined on the Google Form?